# Python raw_input causing EOFError after creating app with py2app

Tags: python, py2app, raw-input, eoferror

I have written a small script that helps me solve scrabble and word-warp problems. It works fine when I run it from Mac OS X terminal. I would like to share the script with my friends as a standalone Mac app. Hence I used py2app for this, but the App crashed when I double-click on it. The console shows the following error message:

```
1/17/11 2:13:51 PM [0x0-0x4a44a4].org.pythonmac.unspecified.warp[9875] Enter letters: Traceback (most recent call last):
1/17/11 2:13:51 PM [0x0-0x4a44a4].org.pythonmac.unspecified.warp[9875]   File "/Users/***/wordwarp/dist/warp.app/Contents/Resources/__boot__.py", line 137, in <module>
1/17/11 2:13:51 PM [0x0-0x4a44a4].org.pythonmac.unspecified.warp[9875]     _run('warp.py')
1/17/11 2:13:51 PM [0x0-0x4a44a4].org.pythonmac.unspecified.warp[9875]   File "/Users/***/wordwarp/dist/warp.app/Contents/Resources/__boot__.py", line 134, in _run
1/17/11 2:13:51 PM [0x0-0x4a44a4].org.pythonmac.unspecified.warp[9875]     execfile(path, globals(), globals())
1/17/11 2:13:51 PM [0x0-0x4a44a4].org.pythonmac.unspecified.warp[9875]   File "/Users/***/wordwarp/dist/warp.app/Contents/Resources/warp.py", line 4, in <module>
1/17/11 2:13:51 PM [0x0-0x4a44a4].org.pythonmac.unspecified.warp[9875]     word = raw_input("Enter letters: ")
1/17/11 2:13:51 PM [0x0-0x4a44a4].org.pythonmac.unspecified.warp[9875] EOFError: EOF when reading a line
1/17/11 2:13:51 PM warp[9875] warp Error
1/17/11 2:13:51 PM warp[9875] warp Error
1/17/11 2:13:52 PM com.apple.launchd.peruser.501[469] ([0x0-0x4a44a4].org.pythonmac.unspecified.warp[9875]) Exited with exit code: 255
```

Here is the actual script:

```
import string

word = raw_input("Enter letters: ")
dict = open('dict.txt')
wordmap = {}
for c in string.lowercase:
    wordmap[c] = 0

for c in word:
    if c in wordmap:
        wordmap[c] = wordmap[c]+1

for line in dict:
    line = line.strip()
    if len(line) >= 3:
        linemap = {}
        for c in string.lowercase:
            linemap[c] = 0
        for c in line:
            if c in linemap:
                linemap[c] = linemap[c]+1
        match = True
        for c in linemap:
            if linemap[c] > wordmap[c]:
                match = False
        if match is True:
            print line
```

How can I get rid of the error?

Answer (score 2):

Python programs wrapped as apps by `py2app` do not have a terminal window from which to enter input.  You would need to supply some fancier way of enter input and suppling output, for example by using Python's `Tkinter` module.  If your script runs from the terminal and you want to make a clickable application, it would likely be simpler to package it as an `Automater` or `AppleScript` application that launches a `Terminal` session.

Comment: I see. What would be the easiest way to do this using either Automator or AppleScript (I have never used either before)? There are just two files: warp.py and dict.txt

Comment: I haven't used py2app, but would it be acceptable to read `word` in from a file or a command-line option?

Comment: The reason for using `py2app` in the first place is to produce a standard OS X GUI application that can be launched by double-clicking in the Finder.  In that case, there is no command line.  If your application is expected to be run from a shell command line, then you most likely shouldn't be using `py2app`.  Just package it with Python Distutils and a console script like most cross-platform Python packages do.