# Python to Mac .app (EOFError caused by raw_input)

Tags: python, xcode, macos, applescript

So, basically I have a python script which I would like to convert into a Mac Application (.app). The basic structure of the code is this:

```
while 1:
    command_handler(raw_input("> ",))
```

What I have here is actually a [REPL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop), which takes input from the user and responds accordingly.

I have tried exporting it with py2app, Platypus, Xcode, Build Applet, AppleScript. Most of them throw an error:

```
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

Xcode doesn't let me export (I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5276967/python-in-xcode-4) to set it up accordingly), it doesn't even create an archive.

Build Applet makes an .app, but when I open it, it closes immediately.

The rest of them throw the `EOFError`.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4711589/python-raw-input-causing-eoferror-after-creating-app-with-py2app) which is about `py2app` and the like giving the `EOFError` while using `raw_input`. Hope this can lead you in the right direction, I would help test some things out but I am on Windows.

Comment: I've just tried it with Automator. Same thing as AppleScript, same thing as always: `EOFError`.

Comment: [The answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4711673/2037884) and the comments on that question mention you cannot do this with `raw_input` as you need a terminal open. The last comment on this answer `Just package it with Python Distutils and a console script like most cross-platform Python packages do.` Is this what you're wanting to do? If so, go with just a console script, else you're left with using a GUI library like `Tkinter`.

Comment: I found a better way. I wrote a script in AppleScript which opens a terminal window and runs the .py script from the resources of the app build. It was a little complicated, but it works fine. Thanks for all the help!