# Py2app returning main error with raw_input

Tags: python, py2exe, py2app

For school, I needed to make a basic Python application. This application ran off of user inputs (`raw_input`) and used `if` statements which would then link to another function. I need to turn this into a standalone application using py2app. The only issue is when I click to open the application I get:

```
EOF error: EOF when reading a line**.
```

This happens immediately after the line:

```
name = raw_input ("What is your name? >>")
```

I have heard that py2app has some difficulty with using `raw_input` but I need some way to allow for the user to input responses in a fairly simple manner, which will also work with py2app.

Mac OSX 10.10.3

Comment: What is the rest of your code?

Answer (score 0):

raw_input() tries to read user input from the **console**, which you won't have available when developing with py2app.

You will have to research other way of gathering input, such as Python standard GUI (Graphical User Interface), [TkInter](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TkInter).

EDIT: Exactly the same question as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4711589/python-raw-input-causing-eoferror-after-creating-app-with-py2app).